# How can i get the text of an element on html using Family properties?

Tags: javascript, html

I wanna get the text on an element using family properties with javascript function, one of these (firstChild, nextSibling , parent...)

1. i click on button .
2. get the text from the `<a>Hello</a>` element which is
   **Hello**
3. store the text on a variable

```
<div class="swiper-slide">
    <i class="fa-regular fa-pen-to-square" id="update_pen"  onclick="update_function()"></i> <--- click here
    <div class="services-item mb-40 elementor-repeater-item-78d8e80" id="swiper-slide-one">
        <div class="services-item__content">
            <h4 class="services-item__tp-title mb-30">
                <a href="service-details.html">Hello</a> <---- this text
            </h4>

            <div class="text_area_box" id="text_area_box">
                <input type="text" name="" required="">
                <label>Titre</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `addEventListener()` to bind your handler so that you can get a reference to the element from the Event that's raised, not an outdated `onclick` attribute.
2. Use [`closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to get the nearest `.swiper-slide` element.
3. Use `querySelector()` to get the child `a` element.
4. Read its `textContent`

Also, given the context and purpose of the question, I assume the HTML structure is repeated multiple times. As such you need to remove the `id` attributes from all elements that are repeated as `id` must be unique within the DOM.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('i.button').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const parent = e.target.closest('.swiper-slide');
    const text = parent.querySelector('a').textContent;
    console.log(text);
    
    const input = parent.querySelector('input');
    input.value = text;
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="swiper-slide">
  <i class="button fa-regular fa-pen-to-square">Click</i>
  <div class="services-item mb-40 elementor-repeater-item-78d8e80">
    <div class="services-item__content">
      <h4 class="services-item__tp-title mb-30">
        <a href="service-details.html">Hello</a>
      </h4>
      <div class="text_area_box">
        <input type="text" name="" required="" />
        <label>Titre</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">
  <i class="button fa-regular fa-pen-to-square">Click</i>
  <div class="services-item mb-40 elementor-repeater-item-78d8e80">
    <div class="services-item__content">
      <h4 class="services-item__tp-title mb-30">
        <a href="service-details.html">Goodbye</a>
      </h4>
      <div class="text_area_box">
        <input type="text" name="" required="" />
        <label>Titre</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how can i put the **text** on the **text_area_box** input value ?

Comment: You can use the same approach to select the `input`, then set its `value` property. I've edited the answer to give you an example of this

Answer (score 1):

You can give an id to the element you want to store:

```
<a id="hello" href="service-details.html">Hello</a>
```

Declare a variable `const variable = ""`

And then you can use
`variable = document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML` in your button function in order to store the contents